# Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API: Can't set batchsize to 1

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

If I Change the `batchsize` to `1` with faster `RCNN 640x640` and `ResNet 50` as Backbone,

I get the following Error:

```
The 'global_batch_size' 1 is not divisible by 'num_replicas_in_sync' 4
How can I set the batchsize to 1?
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may imagine, the problem in your case is that you are actually trying to use 4 video cards/devices (`num_replicas_in_sync`), but your batch_size is 1. Needless to say, you cannot train with 1 batch size to with on 4 devices.

There are two solutions:

1. Either change `num_replicas_in_sync` to 1.
2. Either increase the `global_batch_size` to a value which is divisible by 4 (4,8,12 etc.)